# How to implement ASP.NET Identity 2.0 in multi-tier solution

Tags: asp.net, wcf, asp.net-identity-2

I'm looking for some guidance as to how to implement ASP.NET identity 2 in a multi-tier environment. I have a physically separated presentation and business layer, but all of the examples and sample code I have seen for Identity all involve using EF right from the presentation layer to the DB. Instead of hitting the DB direct, I will have a set of WCF services as my business layer (pretty typical I'm sure). I'm good with using EF at the bottom as an ORM, but only from within the web services, not the presentation layer.

I am assuming the most straight forward approach would be to have custom implementations of IUser*Store interfaces, then those implementations would call the back-end web services.

Is this the recommended approach, or is there a different way of doing this? It seems appropriate as this seems to be the recommended way to implement your own custom user store, but it seems pretty heavy to have to implement all of those interfaces (I know most are optional, but I will need most of them).

Comment: I think you've confused presentation layer's meaning. Just because you have an ORM in your site doesn't mean it's in the presentation layer, as you can have multiple layers in your site (though I'd normally split them out into separate projects that I'd reference.)

Comment: @mason I don't think I've confused anything. I'm not talking about having multiple layers in the same site, I'm talking about multiple physical tiers. My ORM won't sit on the presentation layer server, it will sit on another completely separate box accessible only via web services. I think you are confusing the concept of logical layers with physical tiers, or perhaps you think I am :)

Comment: Your last description just convinced me even more of that. In any case, if you want to use Identity with your WCF as the data layer, you'll need to write your own custom Identity provider.

Comment: @mason, but I'm talking specifically in the context of ASP.NET Identity 2.X. As far as I can tell, this would be hidden behind the IUser*Store interfaces, but I'm looking for confirmation on this as I've not seen any guidance anywhere.